# What does the laplace transform do really?

Tags: laplace-transform, control-theory

From the solution method of second degree differential equations we know that a system can be modelled as $ce^{(\lambda + \omega i)t}$. The complex constant contains information about the decay rate (real component) and the natural frequency (imaginary component) of the system.

Looking at the definition of Laplace Transform, I see:

$$\int_0^\infty e^{-st} f(t) dt$$

This integral clearly extracts knowledge on this complex constant, hence it allows us to analyze the system in more general terms. We pass from the time domain to the frequency domain.

But how does it happen? In the definition above I sense some kind of "squeeze" (where $s$ is also a complex number) but I am unable to understand it intuitively. If I can get to understand it, this would vehemently aid my study of the topic. Thanks.

Comment: I think it's best understood via Fourier transforms instead which can be understood first via Fourier series. Laplace transforms are effectively the imaginary frequency domain of a Fourier transform (for a function supported on the half line). Fourier transforms are not quite as useful for time-domain ODEs for technical reasons, but the Laplace transform is as the integral kernel has exponential decay which allows for the transform of a much wider set of functions. Laplace transforms are a bit like a Wick rotation of Fourier transforms.

Comment: Fourier series decompose functions in terms of complex exponentials with the interpretation that the coefficients correspond to how loud certain frequencies are. Fourier series are constrained to bounded intervals. Fourier transforms are a way to extend Fourier series to infinite intervals and has the same interpretation as Fourier series: the amplitude of the Fourier transform corresponds to how loud a certain frequency is (proportionately).

Comment: In $e^{-st}$, if $t$ is in seconds, then $s$ must be in $\text{sec}^{-1}$, or frequency.  Because $\exp$ can be applied only to unitless quantities.

Comment: If you let $s= \sigma+i\omega$, then you can view the Laplace transform as the Fourier transform of the 'mollified' function $t \mapsto e^{-\sigma t} f(t)$. The integral of the latter is defined for a wider variety of functions than when $\sigma=0$, and the useful properties of the Fourier transform still apply.